# Yii 2 получить данные из модели модуля

Tags: php, yii2

подскажите как вызвать метод из модели. предположим \yii2test\views\site\index.php
а модель \yii2test\modules\admin\models\Post.php

```
public static function init_post()
{
    return $text = Post::find()
            ->orderBy([
                'f_timestamp' => SORT_DESC,
            ])
            ->limit(10)
            ->all();
}
```

app\modules\admin\models\Post::init(); дает Cannot make non static method yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::init() static in class app\modules\admin\models\Post

т.е. есть модель в модуле. у неё есть метод, возвращающий массив. мне нужно этот массив получить во вью и отрисовать

т.е. сконектить вью и модель
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых init не статичный метод. Во-вторых: зачем вы в init всё это задаёте? Метод `Model::init()` вызывается при инициализации модели.

Comment: я не знал что он зарегистрирован этот метод изменил название

Comment: Да, метод `init` используется в yii2 [практически везде](https://goo.gl/oNd72P). Его можно использовать вместо `__construct`, что задать некую логику при инициализации модели, котроллера и т.д. В `index.php` находится логика bootstrap-а приложение (единая точка входа). Далее, отрабатыват маршрутизатор, и в зависимости от парматров ([правил для роутинга](https://goo.gl/SuZ2XY)) указанных в конфиге, запрос направляется в конкретный action котроллера. На вашем изображение, это `PostController`. Именно в нём вы должны получить данные из модели `Post` и отправить в view.

Answer (score 1):

модель

```
public static function initPost()
{
    return static::find()
                    ->orderBy([
                        'f_timestamp' => SORT_DESC,
                    ])
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->all();
}
```

view

```
$arr =   app\modules\admin\models\Post::initPost();
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтоб

> сконектить вью и модель

в MVC применяют контроллер.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->render('название файла вида', 
            ['model' => Post::init_post()]
        );
    }
}
```

Этот метод передаст в вид переменные, которые были сгенерированы из массива `Post::init_post()` функцией [extract](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php) Т.е. в виде они будут доступные как переменные, с названиями аналогичными названиями ключей в массиве. По умолчанию Yii2 будет искать вид по маршруту `views/NameOfModule/NameOfController/index.php`